# NRF52 java unsigned byte issue

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am using ble with nrf52 and sending a byte array command from android with java like below

```
byte[] header=new byte[]{
            (byte )0x5f,
            (byte) 0xf0,
            (byte) 0xf1,
            (byte) 0xf2,
    };
```

when I log these bytes to console, I see as below

```
[111,-16,-15,-14]
```

Device gots the command but doesn't send answer

However, if I send the same command from iOS with swift, command data showns as below

```
[111,240,241,242]
```

and works as aspected.

What may cause this behavior? May it be related java's unsingned byte support?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. While your iOS App handles the received data as 'unsigned bytes' the Android App interprets them as 'signed bytes'. You might want to treat them as unsigned values with the corresponding *unsigned methods, for example [Byte.compareUnsigned](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte#compareUnsigned(byte,%20byte))

Comment: Actually, the problem is not about parsing the received data, iti is about sending the command. From java, same command (wihch is header byte array upside of the question) is not working but sending from ios with swift, it works.

Comment: Yepp, I totally agree. But _you_ write the code and you decide whether the data is treated as signed or unsigned data.  And you don't even show us your Android source code where the data is sent. How do you expect people to help you?